# How to monitor Flux.onBackpressureBuffer() queue size

Tags: project-reactor

In my reactive application I have hot `Publisher` with slow `Subscriber`. To handle lack of demand I am using onBackpressureBuffer but possible overflow errors are kinda scary.

How can I monitor number of elements present in the queue created by `Flux.onBackpressureBuffer(maxSize)`? Preferably with built-in reactor `metrics()` method. I am using Spring Boot + Micrometer if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 4):

Although we didn't we find an easy way to this in Reactor, but we found a bit "hacky" one. Here it is: https://github.com/allegro/envoy-control/blob/master/envoy-control-core/src/main/kotlin/pl/allegro/tech/servicemesh/envoycontrol/utils/ReactorUtils.kt#L34

This function measures buffer size of various Flux operators. It is not guaranteed to work on every operator, but it was tested on `onBackpressureBuffer` with positive results.
It is written in Kotlin, but it should be very easy to port it to Java.

The essence of this code in case of `onBackpressureBuffer` is to cast `Subscription` to `Scannable`, and then use BUFFERED attribute:

```kotlin
flux
  .onBackressureBuffer(maxSize)
  .doOnSubscribe { subscription -> 
     // ...
     val queueSize = Scannable.from(subscription).scan(Scannable.Attr.BUFFERED)
     // ...
  }
```